# Covariant derivative, parallel transport, Christoffel symbols

Tags: derivatives, manifolds, partial-derivative, smooth-manifolds

I would like to see the **geometric** intuition behind how linear combination of the Christoffel symbols give the covariant derivative **and** parallel transport

$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}}=\Gamma^k_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an $(d-1)$-dimensional manifold $M \subset \mathbb R^d$ parametrized by $\mathbf{r}(t_1, \ldots, t_{d-1}).$ Let $\mathbf{e}_k = \partial_k \mathbf{r} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t_k} \mathbf{r},$ which is in the tangent spaces of $M.$ Then $\{ \mathbf{e}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{e}_{d-1}, \mathbf{n} \},$ where $\mathbf{n}$ is a normal, constitutes a local basis of $\mathbb R^d,$ so
$$\partial_k \mathbf{e}_l = \Gamma_{kl}^m \mathbf{e}_m + \omega_{kl} \mathbf{n},$$
for some coefficients $\Gamma_{kl}^m$ and $\kappa_{kl}.$ Skipping the *extrinsic* term $\omega_{kl} \mathbf{n},$ we have $\partial_k \mathbf{e}_l = \Gamma_{kl}^m \mathbf{e}_m,$ to be compared with the formula in the question.

Now let $\mathbf{u}$ be a vector field tangent to $M.$ Then we can write $\mathbf{u} = u^l \mathbf{e}_l$ and
$$
\partial_k \mathbf{u} 
= \partial_k (u^l \mathbf{e}_l) 
= (\partial_k u^l) \mathbf{e}_l + u^l (\partial_k \mathbf{e}_l) \\
= (\partial_k u^l) \mathbf{e}_l + u^l \Gamma_{kl}^m \mathbf{e}_m
= (\partial_k u^m) \mathbf{e}_m + u^l \Gamma_{kl}^m \mathbf{e}_m \\
= (\partial_k u^m + u^l \Gamma_{kl}^m) \mathbf{e}_m
\equiv (D_k u^m) \mathbf{e}_m.
$$
(Here only the intrinsic part has been considered. The extrinsic part can easily be added.)

A parallel transport corresponds to $\partial_k \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0}$ (intrisically), i.e. to
$$\partial_k u^m + u^l \Gamma_{kl}^m = 0.$$

---

**EDIT**
Including the extrinsic term, we have
$$
\partial_k \mathbf{u} 
= \partial_k (u^l \mathbf{e}_l) 
= (\partial_k u^l) \mathbf{e}_l + u^l (\partial_k \mathbf{e}_l) \\
= (\partial_k u^l) \mathbf{e}_l + u^l (\Gamma_{kl}^m \mathbf{e}_m + \omega_{kl} \mathbf{n})
= (\partial_k u^m) \mathbf{e}_m + u^l \Gamma_{kl}^m \mathbf{e}_m + u^l \omega_{kl} \mathbf{n} \\
= (\partial_k u^m + u^l \Gamma_{kl}^m) \mathbf{e}_m + u^l \omega_{kl} \mathbf{n}
\equiv (D_k u^m) \mathbf{e}_m + u^l \omega_{kl} \mathbf{n}.
$$

Comment: Could you please add the extrinsic part? I do not even know what that word (extrinsic) means.

Comment: I use *intrinsic* when something belongs to the manifold or its tangentspaces, and *extrinsic* when it only exists when the manifold is embedded, e.g. the normal. The extrinsic term/part refers to $\omega_{kl} \mathbf{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let :

- $\pi : P\to M$ be a $G$-principal bundle over $M$
- $\mathfrak g := \mathrm{Lie}(G)$
- $A$ be a connexion form on $P$
- $s_\alpha : U_\alpha\to P$ be a local section of $P$
- Consider the pull-back $A_\alpha := s_\alpha^*A \in \Omega^1(U_\alpha;\mathfrak g)$.

Now, in coordinates on $U_\alpha\subset M$ and given a basis of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ the local 1-form $A_\alpha$ has some coefficients that you can write $\Gamma^k_{ij}$.

In your case, $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ being the Christoffel symbols it is assumed that $P$ is the frame bundle $\mathrm{Fr}(M)$ and $G=\mathrm{GL}(n)$ where $n:=\dim M$. Intuitively, the $\Gamma^{k}_{ij}$'s are then coefficients of a connexion form pulled-back to $U_\alpha\subset M$. This depends on $A$ and on $s_\alpha$. Although the $\Gamma^k_{ij}$'s coefficients depends on $s_\alpha$, the covariant derivative and parallel transport geometrically don't (otherwise those wouldn't generically be globally defined).

**Covariant derivative :**
A vector field $X\in \mathfrak X(M)$ is a section of the associated bundle $TM$ of $\mathrm{Fr}(M)$. To $X$ corresponds a $\mathrm{GL}(n)$-equivariant function $X^\sharp : \mathrm{Fr}(M)\to \mathbb R^n$. The covariant derivative $\nabla X$ corresponds to the horizontal component of $\mathrm d X^\sharp$.

**Parallel transport :**
Let $v\in T_x M$ be a tangent vector. To $v$ corresponds a $\mathrm{GL}(n)$-equivariant function $v^\sharp:\pi^{-1}(x)\to \mathbb R^n$. Consider a smooth path $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$. Now, $A$ and $\gamma$ induce a 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms $\phi_t:\pi^{-1}(x)\to \pi^{-1}(\gamma_t)$ given by *following* the horizontal distribution on $\mathrm{Fr}(M)$. Then the pull-back $(\phi_t^{-1})^*v^\sharp$ is a $\mathrm{GL}(n)$-equivariant function on the fiber $\pi^{-1}(\gamma_t)$ and so corresponds to a family of vector $w_t\in T_{\gamma_t} M$. That family of vectors $w_t$ is the parallel transport of $v$ along $\gamma$ relative to $A$.

*Remark :* There are other simpler descriptions of covariant derivatives and parallel transport to give intuition, which you can find on Wikipedia for example. But, a precise geometrical intuition given in terms of principal bundles is way more solid for further studies. I encourage you to read about that theory. The classical book about it is from Kobayashi and Nomizu. There are other books of course.